# Background check - how many years back info required - US hire

Tags: resume, job-offer, new-job, work-experience

hi I got an offer from a large company subject to passing background check. Does anyone has experience using First Advantage. Whatever agency you have used, can you pl tell how long back they want to verify previous employment history. 15 years or 20 years ? I worked abroad for a few years and lost touch with those team mates, companies merged etc. Just wanted to check so I can start digging those contacts or alert them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's entirely up to your employer as to how deep they want to look.  Even if they do care that far back, it's almost certainly just going to be an HR check (just start/end dates).  And probably not even that if the company has gone out of business.

Comment: Background check could include university/education... Some of those who have been caught passing secrets were recruited when they were students...

Answer (score 1):

**At least everything on the resume, and probably any academic credentials as well.**

Any job you listed on your resume is certainly fair game, and depending on what position you are up for, they could desire all of your work experience from your entire life.  I met a guy at hackathon who complained about having to dig up the name of the ice cream stand he worked for at 15 for one background check for a new grad position.

I think it would be worthwhile just to get in touch with everybody. It is a great excuse to go and renew the freshness of your network.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what they'll check for sure:

1. Your eligibility to be employed in the USA
2. Your credentials (schools, employment status, etc)

Here's what they *MIGHT* check depending on your job:

1. Possibly your criminal history depending on your position (sometimes a speeding/parking ticket might matter if you're going to be hired for a driver)
2. Credit history if you're going to banks or anything financial they might check into it

It's not a deep scope background check where they go out and ask everyone about your entire life. Chances are they probably won't even call anyone on your reference. However, it is a very good idea to give people who you listed a heads up. I would recommend that you get permission from the person before listing him/her as a reference. They probably won't get called but sometimes a background agency or even an HR rep might just give one person a ring and all they would ask is if they know X, and all they would ask is if they think X is a good worker.

Keep in mind companies don't really disclose why you were let go of. So if you were fired from a company, they would at most just say you were let go of on such and such date. Now that same thing doesn't apply to references. So if you have a reference who know you were fired, he/she might say it to the person like, "Oh yeah, X was fired for coming in late all the time."

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the background check company. I had a background check where they absolutely had to contact every past job on my resume and held things up for a week when they had problems reaching one. After that I took the oldest/hardest to reach stuff off of my resume. As Dan Is Fiddling By Firelight said in a comment, they just need HR. Although they will ask deeper questions if they reach someone who knows deeper stuff.